# How to wait for a user to respond with a value and copy that value

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically, I am trying to make a command that will ask the user some questions and format all of the questions into an embed. I know how to make the embed and such, but I do not know how to make the bot wait for the user to respond to that message.

In this case, the message the bot will send is "Enter your profile link" (In an embed) and the user should respond with their profile link, then the bot will delete both the user's response and the message he sent.

Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def messageembed(ctx):
   await ctx.message.delete()
   embed = discord.Embed(
       colour=discord.Colour.blue()
   )
   embed.set_author(name='Enter your profile link')
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
   profile_link = await client.wait_for("message")
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or issues when using the code?

Comment: No I don't get any error.

Comment: Okay, so **what is the question**? What happens when you try this code? What is supposed to happen instead, and **how is that different**?

Comment: My question is how do I get the value, and then delete both the message from the bot and the message from the user. For example if after that question I send "link" I would like profile_link to be "link" instead of a line with the user, the ID and all that stuff, which happens right now. And then I would like the bot to delete his question and the answer.

Comment: The value of what ? Also, to delete the message calling for the bot, you can use `await ctx.message.delete()`, but I don't know how to delete a message produced by the bot.

Comment: This is what profile_link is after receiving an answer:

<Message id=1020708835888988382 channel=<TextChannel id=889532840579059763 name='bot-commands' position=15 nsfw=False news=False category_id=702991078483296337> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id= ID name='name' discriminator='0001' bot=False nick='name'  guild=<Guild id=702658487813144579 name='server' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=15>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def messageembed(ctx):
   await ctx.message.delete()
   embed = discord.Embed(
       colour=discord.Colour.blue()
   )
   embed.set_author(name='Enter your profile link')
   profile_link_question = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
   def check(m): return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
   profile_link = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=300)
   await ctx.send(profile_link.content)
```